# Dice roll combinations java

Tags: java

I'm having some troubles getting this code to look neat since there are som many IF & OR statement that needs to be evaulated.

Idea: You throw five dices and pick out e.g. three of the same type 1,1,1 and throw dice the other two again and go gather points.

The tricky thing is to compare dice1,dice2,dice3,dice4,dice5 with the set of rules in order to determine how many points the player get. What code would check all the possible combination "if dicex=1 & dicex=1 & dicex=1" give player 1000 points?

```
int player1points = 0;
int player2points = 0;
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
Random n1 = new Random();
int dice1 = n1.nextInt(6) + 1;
int dice2 = n1.nextInt(6) + 1;
System.out.println("Dice 1 shows " +dice1);
System.out.println("Dice 2 shows " +dice2);
System.out.println("Dice 3 shows " +dice3);
System.out.println("Dice 4 shows " +dice4);
System.out.println("Dice 5 shows " +dice5);

if /* 1+1+1+1+1 = 2000 */ (dice1==1&&dice2==1&&dice3==1&&dice4==1&&dice5==1){ 

System.out.println("You got 2000 points! Throw again?");
int points2000 = 2000;
player1points = player1points + points2000;
System.out.print("You have ");
System.out.print(player1points);
System.out.print(" points. Do you want to throw again?");
System.out.println("Yes/No?");
s = in.nextLine();
}   

else if /* 1+1+1 = 1000 */     (dice1==1&&dice2==1&&dice3==1||dice2==1&&dice3==1&&dice4==1||dice3==1&&dice4==1&&dice5==1|| dice4==1&&dice5==1&&dice1==1||dice5==1&&dice1==1&&dice2==1||dice1==1&&dice2==1&&dice4==1||d    ice2==1&&dice3==1&&dice5==1||dice3==1&&dice4==1&&dice1==1||dice4==1&&dice5==1&&dice1==1||dice1==1&&dice3==1&&dice5==1){ 
System.out.println("You got 1000 points!");
int points1000 = 1000;
player1points = player1points + points1000;
System.out.print("You have ");
System.out.print(player1points);
System.out.print(" points. Do you want to throw again?");
System.out.println("Yes/No?");
s = in.nextLine();

}
```

Comment: This is not Javascript...

Comment: @AnubianNoob Then I seen the code and tag... I fixed though :P

Comment: Just FYI, because even a lot of native English speakers get it wrong: "dice" is the plural (more than one). "Die" is the singular. E.g., one die, two dice. (The word "dices" is unrelated to the six-sided objects in question; it's a conjugation of a completely unrelated verb.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm English native, and I didn't know that... +1 for learning Grammar on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the results of the rolls into an arrayList, then just count the number of times the same number shows up in that array list?  If there are 3 1's, give 1000 points, else if there are 5 1's give 2000 points.

So for your code you'll have the same beginning for the most part. Add in methods to populate the array list, and to iterate though/count the results of the dice rolls and return the most common and the number of times it shows up.

```
int player1points = 0;
int player2points = 0;
int count = 0;
int mostCommon = 0;
int maxCount = 0;
ArrayList<Integer> diceRolls = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
Random n1 = new Random();

//rollDice method (parameter would be number of dice to roll)

//checkResults method (count number of times each number 1-6 shows up)

if(maxCount == 3){
    player1points += 1000;
    //re-roll 2 dice if necessary
else if(maxCount == 5){
    player2points += 2000;
    //re-roll dice if wanted
```

That's just one way you could do it. Also it's always good practice to break big blocks of code down into more reader-friendly functions, and it makes debugging easier! If you need anymore help feel free to ask!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Make your answer a statement, and maybe provide some code, so your answer is more helpful.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll fix it up asap.